# Hessian matrix of $ \log(1+\exp(a^Tx) )$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

I need to compute the Hessian matrix of $ ( \log(1+\exp(a^Tx))  $ where $a$ is a vector of constants. I was able to compute the Hessian matrix for  $ (1+\exp(a^Tx)) $ but not sure how to proceed. I know I should use the fact that I have a composition of functions but not sure exactly how.

Comment: What is the problem with computing directly the Hessian of the desired function ? You can go from the one you have derived to the the wanted one but it seems [harder](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870669/hessian-of-a-composition-of-maps) in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define

$$ f : \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto \log\left(1 + \exp\left( a^{\top} x \right) \right), $$
where we adopt the convention that $a = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_N \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ is a column vector (and all vectors are assumed to be column vectors in the following). For convenience, let
$$T_1 : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : \xi \mapsto \log(\xi)$$
and
$$ T_2 : \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto 1 + \exp\left( a^{\top} x \right). $$
Then, $f = T_1 \circ T_2,$ and

- $\nabla T_1(x) = \frac{1}{x} \in \mathbb{R};$
- $\nabla^2 T_1(x) = - \frac{1}{x^2} \in \mathbb{R};$
- $\nabla T_2(x) = a \exp\left( a^{\top} x \right) \in \mathbb{R}^{N};$
- $\nabla^{2} T_2(x) = a a^{\top} \exp\left( a^{\top} x \right) \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}.$

Hence,
$$\nabla f(x) = a \left[ \frac{\exp\left( a^{\top} x \right)}{1 + \exp\left( a^{\top} x \right)} \right] = \left[ 1 + \exp\left( a^{\top} x \right) \right]^{-1} a \exp\left( a^{\top} x \right) \in \mathbb{R}^{N} $$ and
\begin{align*}
\nabla^{2}f(x) &= -\left[ 1 + \exp\left( a^{\top} x \right) \right]^{-2} a a^{\top} \exp\left( a^{\top} x \right)^{2} + \left[ 1 + \exp\left( a^{\top} x \right) \right]^{-1} a a^{\top} \exp\left( a^{\top} x \right) \\
&= a a^{\top} \left( \left[ 1 + \exp\left( a^{\top} x \right) \right]^{-1} \exp\left( a^{\top} x \right) - \left[ 1 + \exp\left( a^{\top} x \right) \right]^{-2} \exp\left( 2 a^{\top} x \right) \right) \\
&= a a^{\top} \left( \frac{\exp\left( a^{\top} x \right)}{1 + \exp\left( a^{\top} x \right)} - \frac{\exp\left( 2 a^{\top} x \right)}{\left[ 1 + \exp\left( a^{\top} x \right) \right]^2} \right) \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N},
\end{align*}
where
$$ a a^{\top} = \begin{bmatrix} a^{2}_1 & a_{1} a_2 & \cdots & a_{1} a_N \\
a_2 a_1 & a^{2}_2 & \cdots & a_2 a_N \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_N a_1 & a_N a_2 & \cdots & a^{2}_N
 \end{bmatrix}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Call your given expression $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ Then $$\nabla f=[\frac{a_1\exp(\mathbf{a^Tx})}{1+\exp(\mathbf{a^Tx})},...   ,\frac{a_n\exp(\mathbf{a^Tx})}{1+\exp(\mathbf{a^Tx})}]$$ Then each of the entries $f_{ij}$ of the Hessian matrix can be found by applyingthe quotient rule to calculate the appropriate second-order partial derivative.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient of your function is easily found to be
$$\mathbf{g}
= \sigma(z) \mathbf{a}
$$
where $z=\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}$ and $\sigma(z)$ is the sigmoid function.

The differential follows
\begin{eqnarray*}
d\mathbf{g}
&=& 
\sigma(z)[1-\sigma(z)] \mathbf{a} dz \\
&=& 
\sigma(z)[1-\sigma(z)] \mathbf{a} \mathbf{a}^T d\mathbf{x}
\end{eqnarray*}
The Hessian writes (as you found)
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{H}
= \sigma(z)[1-\sigma(z)] \mathbf{a} \mathbf{a}^T
\end{equation}